# Using composer for developing two application simultaneously

Tags: php, composer-php, development-environment, dvcs

I am wondering if there is a best practice for developing two (or more) application at the same time and using composer as a dependency manager.

The thing is that I have an application as a "core" (app "A") library and another app (app "B") that requires the first one. Then I make some changes at the app "A" and want to update app "B". As these apps are in different folders and each one has it's own repo I have to commit changes, push them and then run `composer update` in app "B".

Pretty much extra typing, I think. So, may be there are some tried-and-true solutions to deal with this inconvenient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that I find out how to do it.

Have not noticed that composer places a .git directory under a vendor name. So I do not have to keep my "core" project separate from main application. I can edit it, commit and push to its repo and have both applications up to date.